# Checkout operation using SVN Command line

Tags: windows, svn, cmd, svn-checkout

I want to checkout a folder from SVN repository to my local system by command line operation of SVN.

Comment: Use `svn help` to get a list of commands, including checkout. Then, use `svn help co` to get more information about checking out. How you refer to your repo depends on how it was setup. We can't make that up.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example of [SVN documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.html) in which you can find a list of svn command line commands. I'd highly recommend you start a lot of your research there to help you out. It's not really about us, here on StackOverflow, it's more of a waste of your time as this is something that is relatively easy to look up.

Nevertheless, the command you're looking for is [`svn checkout`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.checkout.html) or `svn co`

The syntax is really straight forward:

`svn co url/to/repository/trunk my/local/path`

And this will checkout the folder `trunk` on your local machine at: `my/local/path`